# NSTableView and NSSearchField in an NSView, which is the outlet of an NSMenuItem, don't work

Tags: cocoa, focus, nstableview, nsview, nsmenuitem

I'm having an `NSView`, which is set as the `view:` outlet of an `NSMenuItem`. The view contains an `NSTableView` (inside an `NSScrollView`) and an `NSSearchField`. The `NSMenu` is shown when the user clicks a specific `NSStatusItem`. When I launch the application from Xcode (Build and Run), the controls behave well, but whenever I launch it from the Finder (like the users would), they don't work and don't take any focus. My application is an `LSUIElement`. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: “… the `view:` outlet …” You mean `view`. Variable and property names can't contain colons, and the getter for the (informal) property is named `view`, with no colon, because it does not take an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, your application is an `UIElement`, it's `NSMenu` won't take focus. You must set an `NSTimer` to 0.01 seconds to show the `NSMenu`, and you should make the application active:

```
- (void)statusItemClicked {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(showMenu) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
- (void)showMenu {
    [statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:statusMenu];
}
```